# Android, Attempting to view PDF within Xamarin Android App

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am attempting to view PDFs through my Android app, and I'm using this library: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.PdfView.Android/

Here's what my code look likes:

C#:

```
using Com.Joanzapata.Pdfview; 
using Java.IO;

namespace Xamarin_test
{
    [Activity(Label = "Xamarin", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            PDFView pdfView = FindViewById<PDFView>(Resource.Id.pdfview);

            pdfView.FromAsset("test.pdf")
                    .DefaultPage(1)
                    .ShowMinimap(false)
                    .EnableSwipe(true)
                    .Load();
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I try running it, I receive this error:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

What is causing this?

Thank you.

Edit, Full error log:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153): Process: Xamarin_MuPDF.Xamarin_MuPDF, PID: 2153
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/Xamarin_MuPDF.Xamarin_MuPDF-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/Xamarin_MuPDF.Xamarin_MuPDF-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libvudroid.so"
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at org.vudroid.core.VuDroidLibraryLoader.load(VuDroidLibraryLoader.java:13)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at org.vudroid.pdfdroid.codec.PdfContext.<clinit>(PdfContext.java:13)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:50)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at com.joanzapata.pdfview.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:1)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-17 15:09:23.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 2153):     ... 3 more
08-17 15:09:26.751 I/Process ( 2153): Sending signal. PID: 2153 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post the full error log.

Comment: I've added the full error log.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens, because you missed to link the `libvudroid.so`. This library is required by pdfview.

You have to

- download the libraries from [here](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/tree/master/android-pdfview/libs)
- create a folder `lib` in your Android project
- copy the folders `arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, armeabi, x86` into the folder
- include the `libvudroid.so` into the project and set the properties (right click on the file -> properties)

  - Build Action: AndroidNativeLibrary
  - Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

[image]

**Troubleshooting**

If you get the build error: `mandroid error XA0000: Invalid create-package command: ...`

- open the project properties
- Android Options
- Advanced
- select all platforms (if all are selected, deselect one and reselect it)
- save
- build again

Comment: Sir, if you were here right now, I'd hug you! You're a super star! Thank you so much for taking the time to write out a very detail explanation of what was going on. I managed to get this working! Again, thank you, sir! If you're ever in Atlanta, hit me up, and I'll take you out for drinks.